# pgfplots: Accessing the Width of a Diagram and Using it as a Variable for other Widths

Tags: pgfplots

I define the width of a plot/diagram using the `width` key, for example:

```
width = 0.8\textwidth,
```

I also define the width of the title text similar:

```
title style = {text width = 0.7\textwidth},
```

I am looking for a way to use the diagramm `width` as a variable in the definition of the `text width` in the `title style`. Here is my "pseudo code wish":

```
title style = {text width = 0.9\myPlotwidth},
```

In this case `\myPlotwidth` (which I inventetd, the key does not exist) would in this case/example be `0.8\textwidth`.

Is there a key like `\myPlotwidth`?

Comment: Is defining a new length and using that an option? `\newlength\myplotwidth\setlength{\myplotwidth}{0.8\textwidth}` and then use `text width=0.9\myplotwidth`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. This is a fallback solution for me. I already use this approach for figures and subfigures. I am just wondering if the plot width is accessible. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like using `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}` works.

In general, if you look in the manual you will see in the description of a key something like

[image]

The value of the key can then be retrieved with `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width = 0.8\textwidth,
title={Some text and more text to make a long title that will break},
title style={text width=0.7*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}]
\addplot[draw=none]{rnd};
\node [align=left] at (rel axis cs:0.5,0.5) {
 Textwidth = \the\textwidth,\\
 Axis width = \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Damn, I get **! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)**.

Comment: My mistake: I need to use the multiplicator symbol *! I don't need that in **0.9\textwidth** but I need it in **0.9*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}**.

Comment: Perfect answer - great!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I made the same mistake at first, until I realized that the value retrieved probably isn't a length in the TeX sense, so that won't work. Luckily calculations are allowed in cases like that.